# Bootstrap 3 form-inline and centered div width to content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm converting a Bootstrap 2.3 layout to Bootstrap 3 and I'm currently stuck with getting a `div` centered, while keeping its width automatically as wide as it's contents.

**EDIT:** an answer below fixed the issue with Firefox, so updated the question to reflect the main problem.

The login form as rendered with Bootstrap 2.3 - content is centered and `.border` and `.well` are only as wide as the content requires:

[image: Bootstrap 2 layout]

Now a try with Bootstrap 3:
http://jsfiddle.net/yq9Ww/13/

[image: BS 3 try]

Evidently something is forcing the `.well` too wide, but for the love of god, I can't figure out how to collapse the width of `.well` to contents.

Can anybody shed light on how to accomplish the same result as with BS 2.3?

PS. I can't fix the width of the `.border` because the same layout is used for much wider content too and that has to fit also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that it was the `.input-group-btn` that messed up my layout, because for one reason or the other Bootstrap has this rule in place:

```
.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn {
  width: 1%;
}
```

And probably in conjunction with other rules it forced the `.well` take all of it's parent's width.

As for `xs` devices the input has to be 100 % wide, then the fix was unset the `width` for non-xs screens:

```
/* .input-group inside .border causes 100% width (some BS3 stuff) */
@media(min-width: 768px){
    div.border .input-group-addon, div.border .input-group-btn {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

And then make `.border` an inline block:

```
div.border {
  /* ... */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is JSFiddle that behaves as expected on all screen sizes:

http://jsfiddle.net/yq9Ww/16/

**UPDATE:** This seems to be issue only in *WebKit* browsers. For Firefox, setting the `inline-block` was enough.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `display: inline-block;` from your custom css.

```
div.border {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    border: 1px solid #205081;
    padding: 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Why don't you define a `min-width` and `max-width` for the `well` element ?

```
.well-medium {
   min-width: 426px;
   max-width: 526px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the Firefox issue, but the main problem still remains - how to collapse the with of `.well`

Comment: I updated the question to clarify and add my recent findings.

Comment: Well, the `max-width` does not help if the lower `.well` does not reach even `min-width`. I think I should go read more about CSS tables - that seems to be closer to the answer.